# Sound Decibel Output Python

Tags: python, audio

I have tried using soundmeter for this specific issue, however, did not really find a way to do it so. I want to get the current PC microphone input, and as an output to get the Decibel of the sound that is recorded by my integrated microphone. Any other libraries that you can suggest? Searched a lot, but did not really find something useful.

Comment: You might want to do some research into the decibel scale: It's a unit-less ratio of relative amplitude or signal power, and not per se a measure of signal power.  For that you need a reference point.    [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) might be a good starting point. You probably want dB FS for this application.

StackOverflow doesn't welcome questions asking for library recommendations.

Comment: @marko I have decided to use "sounddevice" at the end.